# Remove arrows in MUI number textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Quick question, how do I remove arrows in a MUI textfield that is a number type. I tried adding the `MozApperance: 'textfield'`, inside `sx` object but it doesn't work. Here is my short code:

```
            <TextField
                disabled={disabled}
                variant="standard"
                sx={{ width: pageOptions?.width }}
                type="number"
                value={value}
            />
```

If anyone knows how to remove those arrows, I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: If the text field is rendered as a number input you can do this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fast approach

```
sx={{
  width: pageOptions?.width,
  "input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
    WebkitAppearance: "none",
    margin: 0,
  },
  "input[type=number]": {
    MozAppearance: "textfield",
  },
}}
```

### Better approach

If you use a lot of number inputs in your project (and probably you will), You will get a headache copying and pasting these styles in every one of them.
You can define these styles only once in your `theme` component and it will override all of your number input usages.

```
import { createTheme, experimental_sx as sx } from "@mui/material/styles";
let theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: sx({
          "input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button":
            {
              WebkitAppearance: "none",
              margin: 0,
            },
          "input[type=number]": {
            MozAppearance: "textfield",
          },
        }),
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```